# C++ I/O File stream advantages over C language

Tags: c++, c, oop

What are the benefits of specifying an object for file over specifying a pointer for it? How can **OOP** help us with this way of declaring?
in C++ files are read in this way ( It has obejct)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    ifstream InFile;
    InFile.open("/* directory*/");
}
```

whereas in C you declare a **pointer** and then do whatever you  want.

```
   *#include <stdio.h>
      int main()
      { 
           FILE *fptr;
           fptr= fopen("/* directory*/");
           /*..
           .
           .*/
          return 0;
      }
```

I appreciate any good answer.

Comment: 1. 'Pointer to type FILE' is peculiar to the C standard I/O library `stdio`. 2. It *isn't* 'necessary': there are many other ways of doing I/O. 3. `stdio` is peculiarly *un*-suited to network I/O for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

FILE is a data structure which it gets information about file structure in the os. So if you want to work with a file you have to define a variable pointer with that.

FILE defination:

```
typedef struct _iobuf
    {
        void* _Placeholder;
    } FILE;
```

Comment: Pointer is used for storing address not getting information. You're writing to and reading from a file and you include its address in 'fopen() ' function.

Comment: *FILE defination: ...* To be precise, that is **a** definition of a `FILE` structure, for one implementation.  There are many, many other implementation-specific definitiions.  But you shouldn't care because you should *never* access or use anything inside the structure.